# Two "=" characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string, character

How to check in javascript if in the string there are two "=" symbols and to throw a mistake (beacuse for example 1+=2=3 is wrong but 1+2=3 is right)

Comment: we need an example in html css javascript using textarea if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function validateText() {
  const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
  if ((text.match(/=/g)?.length || 0) < 2) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Valid";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Invalid";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>

<button onclick=validateText()>Validate</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: and can you bring an example with the html and textarea too? Please

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_true = '1 + = 2 +  3';
var input_false = '1 + = 2 + = 3';

var success = /^[^=]*=[^=]*$/.test(input_true);      // pass
var not_success = /^[^=]*=[^=]*$/.test(input_false); // fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a little function that uses [a regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) [to test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for this.

```js
function tester(str) {
  return str.match(/=/g).length === 1;
}

console.log(tester('='));
console.log(tester('Bob=='));
console.log(tester('Bob='));
console.log(tester('=Bob=='));
```